# Чем заменить Jetty Proxy Servlet в новом Spring Boot приложении

Tags: spring-boot, proxy

Есть старое приложение, написанное на Java 7 + Jetty. Оно имеет парочку сервлетов.
Также есть 1 сервлет - прокси:

```
    public class MyProxyServlet extends ProxyServlet {

        public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
            // proxy parameters here...
        }

        protected URI rewriteURI(HttpServletRequest request) {
            // proxy requests
            ...
            return new URI(...);
        }

        @Override
        protected HttpClient createHttpClient() throws ServletException {
        }

        protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        }

        public Request addViaHeader(Request proxyRequest) {
        }

    }
```

Сейчас хочу перевести своё мини приложение на Java 17 + Spring Boot. Вопрос такой: на чём в Spring Boot можно реализовать прокси? Просто гуглю и вижу много всего:

- spring-cloud-gateway-mvc
- spring-cloud-starter-zuul
- ...

Что из этого мне нужно? В какую сторону копать, подскажите?

Сам прокси сейчас довольно простой: сначала с помощью LoginServlet мы получаем логин пользователя. И добавляем этот логин в сессию в виде атрибута: `session.setAttribute("login", user);` Далее Прокси Сервлет добавляет header в запрос со значением логина: `proxyRequest.header(headerName, user.getLogin());` и делает форвард запроса дальше. На этом всё.

На чём это можно реализовать в Spring Boot ? Подскажите, пожалуйста.